# How to update deep nested form with redux and its single state tree?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, nested, redux

I have an application in **react** that take a json object as props and render a form for each field of this json so the user can edit the json object.

The json object can be anything, with any depth.

I currently use cursor thanks to this library : [react-cursor](https://github.com/dustingetz/react-cursor). With this library, I can generate my form with any depth and still be able to update my state.

**Example :**

For this json :

```
{
  "object": {
    "subobject": {
      "field": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

I want the following form :

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" value="object"/>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="text" value="subobject"/>
          <ul><li><input type="text" value="field"/></li></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**The problem :** I want to use redux for my app but since cursor update the state instead of creating a new one, I cannot use it for this part of my app.

I've heard about [normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr) but my json's fields don't have ids so I'm not sure it would work in this case.

Any advice ? How should I do with redux to handle this kind of pattern ?

Thanks,

Comment: Redux works ideally if you don't mutate your store. You may need a different library if you need Redux.